# View server login permission

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been working on giving a development team the ability to have read-only access to a SQL environment, I'm at the last step.  I need them to be able to see users/logins and roles.  I noticed that with view defintion granted on any given DB, it allows their login to view the users/roles for each DB, however even granted on master/msdb/model it does not allow the login to view the server wide logins/roles.  What would be the best way to accomplish this? I have tried view defintion and I have tried view server state, neither has worked for server logins to be visible to the user.

Note: I don't want them to have any more access beyond that so I don't want them to be assigned a predefined role.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend writing a stored procedure using [Execute As](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) permissions, and giving them permissions to run that.  Have that stored proc output the list of users and you should be good to go.

Comment: So that is to say that there is no way to simply grant a particular permission that allows them to just use the gui to view the logins as they can do with the users list for any given db?

Comment: You are probably better of asking in http://dba.stackexchange.com/ as most of us are coders, not dbas. :P

Answer (score 0):

I am not a db admin but i read an article related to setting security / permissions using schemas in sql server 2012. I tested a little for setting permissions to some views.

This might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095.aspx